# Jquery does not work on panel which had content dynamically added

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page where I have a panel, which works as a popup when the user clicks a button. The content of this panel is taken from a GET to another PHP file. I need `jquery` to work inside this panel, but unfortunately this is not happening.

I tried adding this on top of the PHP file from which the request was made:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.alert("testing");
    });
</script>
```

So when the panel would be update "testing" should come up on the screen.

I also tried to attach events to a button on the panel, from the main PHP file, but it also didn't work.

How can I make so `jquery` will work on my panel?

How I am adding the content to the panel:

```
function getClink(strcl,strcls)
{ 
    var xmlhttpcl;
    if (strcl=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("divIdclink").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttpcl=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttpcl=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttpcl.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttpcl.readyState == 4 && xmlhttpcl.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("divIdclink").innerHTML=xmlhttpcl.responseText;
            //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttpcl.open("GET","get_close_link_details.php?cl="+strcl+"&cls="+strcls,true);
    xmlhttpcl.send();
}
```

Comment: It's not just jQuery, it's any scripts. If you're using `.load()` with a selector, it strips out any scripts. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Any particular reason you're avoiding [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? I find that they are probably one of the more valuable parts of jQuery, making ajax calls infinitely more easier/fun.. especially without the hassle of all those if statements lol

Comment: I have to agree with @asifrc If you're already using jQuery, why are you not using jQuery to do things that it's good at, such as making Ajax requests?

Comment: If I use Jquery for the ajax calls, will the scripting work?

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery for the ajax call and then call the alert after the content has loaded. Like this

```
$('#clicktoPopUp').click(function(){
    $.get('url', function(data){
       $('#whereYouWantHTML').html(data);
       alert("testing");
    });
});
```

Although if I was doing a dialog popup I would use jQuery UI.